LazyVim: How can I make the erb-formatter work?
I hope not being so noob, but I can't make it works. I am new with LazyVim, reading the documentation I understand that it uses Conform for formatting, then I go to the Conform's documentation and there it is the erb-formatter available, I have this gem installed, I can run it in the terminal. But if I run a :ConformInfo into the buffer there is no formatter available:
Log file: /home/andres/.local/state/nvim/conform.log
          additional information: leftover token
          
          15:52:50[ERROR] Formatter 'stylua' error: error: could not format from stdin: failed to format from stdin: error parsing: error occurred while creating ast: unexpected token `{`. (starting from line 4, character 2 and ending on line 4, character 3)
          additional information: leftover token
          
          16:03:00[WARN] No formatters found for /home/andres/Documentos/Proyectos/opina/app/views/sites/index.html.erb
          16:03:10[WARN] No formatters found for /home/andres/Documentos/Proyectos/opina/app/views/sites/index.html.erb
          16:09:09[ERROR] Formatter 'stylua' error: error: could not format from stdin: failed to format from stdin: error parsing: error occurred while creating ast: unexpected token `=`. (starting from line 5, character 18 and ending on line 5, character 19)
          additional information: expected '}'

Formatters for this buffer:
<none>

Other formatters:
erb_format ready (erb) /home/andres/.local/share/nvim/mason/bin/erb-format
fish_indent ready (fish) /usr/bin/fish_indent
shfmt ready (sh) /home/andres/.local/share/nvim/mason/bin/shfmt
stylua ready (lua) /home/andres/.local/share/nvim/mason/bin/stylua

Now, it appear in "Other formatters" becouse I added a config file trying to make it works giving the file format:
return {
  "stevearc/conform.nvim",
  opts = {
    formatters_by_ft = {
      erb = { "erb_format" },
    },
  },
}

But Still don't works.
I Try installing this with mason.nvim too:
 Installed
    ◍ erb-formatter
    ◍ htmlbeautifier
    ◍ markdownlint
    ◍ shfmt
    ◍ stylua

Can someone help me understand what's wrong with my setup?

I was writing this question and I notice that the :LspInfo command shows like detected filetype "eruby" so I try again the Conform configuration with eruby doctype and it works!
So finally it looks like:
return {
  "stevearc/conform.nvim",
  opts = {
    formatters_by_ft = {
      eruby = { "erb_format" },
    },
  },
}


Thank you. I had the same issue. I do not know why the ft is not set by default

You are welcome. Yes, I think it could be an issue? I don't know.
